# How to convert items in Generic List to comma separated string with Null check

Tags: c#, generics

In a single line. I'm trying to convert a List to Comma Separated Values and check for nulls in a single pass. So how can we do the following:

- Check if generic List lstFoos is empty.
- Return either a comma separated string or string empty?

I've checked but all examples demonstrate this without null/empty list checking.

```
string stringOfCommaSeparatedFoos  =  (lstFoos.Any() ? 
   string.Join(",", lstFoos.Select(x => x.fooItem)).ToArray() : 
          String.Empty);
```

**UPDATE**
I've tried this but it gives null reference exception.
Thanks!

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not very informative. Tell us about the input and desired output.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to check if lstFoos is empty:

```
String.Join(",", lstFoos.Where(x => x != null).Select(x => x.fooItem))
```

If there is nothing to join (empty sequence), then `String.Join` will return empty string by default:

```
public static string Join<T>(string separator, IEnumerable<T> values)
{   
    using (IEnumerator<T> enumerator = values.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!enumerator.MoveNext())        
            return Empty;            
        // ...        
    }
}
```

If you have following fooItem values: `"a", "b", null, "c"` then code above will produce string `"a,b,,c"`

Comment: I think you should check `null` first, what if `x is null` in the `Select`? If so `x.fooItem` will throw exception.

Comment: @KingKing I thought OP does not want null values of `fooItem` in result.. to avoid strings like `a,,,,b`

Comment: after some thought, the OP's code really makes me confused, `lstString` is a `List<string>` so what's `fooItem`?

Comment: @KingKing I think thats a matter of (very) bad naming :)

Comment: @ENC0D3D OK, looks like King was right - you have problems with nulls in your lstFoos. Updated sample